# big and small resolutions of singularities of a 4-fold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

Suppose we have a projective 4fold hypersurface $X\subset P^n$ 
 with ordinary singularities along a smooth curve $C$, and suppose that there exist a projective small resolution $s:Y\to X$. let us denote by $b:Z\to X$ the "big" resolution obtained by blowing-up $C$. is it true that $b$ factors through $s$?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't be true in general.  (Of course, blowing up $C$ might not yield a resolution, but even if it does...).  I don't know an example off the top of my head though.

Comment: Let us supppose it does, just to start with an easier hypothesis.

Comment: Does "ordinary singularities" mean "ordinary double point singularities"?  If so, precisely what do you mean by "ordinary singularities along $C$"?  There is a notion of a "conical stratification" studied by De Concini, MacPherson, Procesi, etc.  This is one way to make this notion precise.  For a conical stratification where the "transverse cone" along $C$ is an ordinary double point, I expect that there is a factorization.

Comment: I also wanted to ask what "ordinary singularities" means in your context. I think that whatever is your assumption, if it implies that blowing up $C$ produces an irreducible exceptional divisor (as in the case of ordinary double points), then what you want is true.

Comment: Thanks for everybody's contribution. I meant exactly  what Jason and Sandor say. Could you shortly explain me why? I also expected this to exist, but could not show this.

Comment: I started writing up my proof... It got pretty involved pretty soon and I am not even sure anymore that it even works. There are some delicate details and I don't have the time to figure it out. Sorry.

Comment: @Sandor I think with more assumptions it is easy to prove --- assume that in the small resolution $s:Y \to X$ the scheme-theoretic preimage of $C$ is a smooth surface. Then blowing up this surface you will get a smooth variety $Z'$ such that the scheme-theoretic preimage of $C$ is a Cartier divisor. By the universal property of a blowup it will give a map $Z' \to Z$. Since both are smooth and have relative Picard number 1 over $X$ it is an isomorphism. What is wrong here?

Comment: @Sasha: Yes, if we assume something about the small resolution, for instance what you are suggesting, that makes it easier, but if the pre-image of $C$ is not "uniform" (e.g., not flat) over $C$, then it gets a little hairy.

Comment: @Sandor: In fact, I would guess that what was meant in the question by "ordinary singularities along a smooth curve" is that locally analytically along $C$ the scheme $X$ is isomorphic to $C\times ODP$ and that one can glue one of the small resolutions of ODP into a globally defined small resolution of $X$. Then of course everything is OK.

Comment: @Sasha: yes, if that is the case (which is sort of what Jason suggested) then it is OK. I assumed that the essential point is whether this is true for **any** small resolution. If the small resolution is obtained by blowing up an ideal with a single prime component, then it is easy. Where I stopped writing up was worrying about embedded components. Also, it seems that the natural statement should be not limited to this dimension and blowing up smooth centers. I started trying to minimize the assumptions, then I realized that while I believe there is a reasonable statement, making into a ...

Comment: ... complete proof would make it pretty long.